# How to parse number of instructions and elapsed time from output of perf stat

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

**TL;DR**

Is there any way to make `perf stat` output time elapsed when `-x` is supplied?

**Background**

I executed `perf stat -e instructions:u make run`, and the output is pasted below.

```
 Performance counter stats for 'make run':

    53,781,961,288      instructions:u

       2.802749955 seconds time elapsed

      21.453244000 seconds user
       0.249223000 seconds sys
```

I would like to parse number of instructions and time elapsed, so I add the `-x` option to make the output separated by comma, and the corresponding output is pasted below.

```
53781782267,,instructions:u,20694056846,100.00,,
```

I noticed that all the time measurements weren't displayed, so I checked the output of `perf help stat`. In the `CSV FORMAT` section, I found that `run time of counter`, `optional metric value`, and `optional unit of metric` may have something to do with my needs, but I couldn't figure out how exactly.

Comment: What is your version of the `perf` and linux kernel?

Comment: @osgx perf: `4.19.g84df95`, linux kernel: `4.17.11-arch1` (by `uname -r`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"time elapsed" is printed from `print_footer` function of [`tools/perf/util/stat-display.c` file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/tools/perf/util/stat-display.c#L1044) if `(config->ru_display)` is true.

But the `print_footer` is not called from `perf_evlist__print_counters` when there is "`-x ,`" option which sets csv_output.

```
if (!interval && !config->csv_output)
    print_footer(config);
```

"user" / "sys" times are in `config->ru_data.ru_utime` and `ru_data.ru_stime` and "seconds time elapsed" is average of `config->walltime_nsecs_stats`.

There is no other code in `stat-display.c` to display `ru_data.ru_utime`, `ru_data.ru_stime` or `walltime_nsecs_stats`, so at Linux kernel version 4.20 it is not possible to output time from the perf stat in CSV mode.

You can patch the `stat-display.c` file to output anything you need and compile the `perf` (`cd tools/perf; make`). perf tool from other kernel version will work with any linux kernel.

Comment: You may try using `perf stat /usr/bin/time -f '%e,%U,%s' ./your_program` to get running time from the GNU time program, or with different format string from [`man time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Does that mean I have to 1. download linux kernel source code 2. modify `<kernel source code dir>/tools/perf/util/stat-display.c` as needed 3. compile it and replace it with the original perf? I'm also wondering whether this would affect other users because I'm working on a workstation. Sorry if this sounds silly to you, I'm taking my first course about linux and trying hard to get familiar with it :)

Comment: David, you can try `perf stat /usr/bin/time -f FORMAT_STRING` solution. Or yes you can download kernel source, change dir to tools/perf, edit file and run make. Than you can't (or should not) replace system perf binary, just run it from the place where it is (or copy it to some your directory like `/home/david/bin/perf`).

Comment: I eventually did used the `FORMAT_STRING` solution, and thank you for all the information!